# merge multiple figures into one pdf using standalone documentclass

Tags: subfloats, document-classes, combine

I have 4 pdf figures which I would like to merge into one pdf figure (requirements of the journal).

I have the follwoing piece of code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=100pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{lastpage,fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}

\begin{figure*}[!h]  %[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\subfigure[{dblp}]{
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{imgs/dblp_corr.pdf}
\label{fig:dblp_corr}
\hspace{-17ex}
}&
\subfigure[{adult}]{
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{imgs/adult_corr.pdf}
\label{fig:adult_core}
\hspace{-17ex}
}&
\subfigure[{census}]{
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{imgs/census_corr.pdf}
\label{fig:census_core}
\hspace{-17ex}
} 
&
\subfigure[{synthetic}]{
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{imgs/synth_corr.pdf}
\label{fig:synthetic}
} 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{\label{fig:corr} The Cramer's V values for all pairs of features
for all datasets.}
\end{figure*}

\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

But the generated pdf is smaller than what I want and only have of the right figure will appear in the figure. 
If I use varwidth like:

`\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=40pt,preview]{standalone}`

the problem will be solved. However there will be margin all (left, right, top, bottom) of the figures. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: compiling with `\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=40pt,preview]{standalone}` i get overlapped figures is that the way you want it (is that right) ? i dont know what size your figures are and if they have the same size or not i just used example-image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to specify a bigger value for the line width (page 19 of the manual of `standalone`.

You don't need a full-fledged `subfigure` (by the way, this package is obsolete, use `subfig` or `subcaption`), nor you need `figure` that just makes a difficult life to `varwidth`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth=30cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,capt-of}

\newcounter{subfloat}
\renewcommand{\thesubfloat}{\alph{subfloat}}
\newcommand{\image}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{subfloat}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  #2 \\
  (\thesubfloat) #1
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\image{dblp}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}%
}\quad
\image{adult}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}%
}\quad
\image{census}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}%
}\quad
\image{synthetic}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}%
}

\captionof{figure}{The Cramer's V values for all pairs of features for all datasets.}

\end{document}
```

[image]